# How to prevent installation of incompatible rpm packages

Tags: yum, rpm, rhel6, specfile

I have two rpm packages that should not get installed together.

After googling around I assume there is no `RequiresNot` tag or something similar to specify incompatible packages in a specfile.

What is the best solution to prevent installing them together?

Currently I'm using rhel but I would prefer a solution that is not `rhel/yum` related (eq using: `exclude=packageA` in repo.conf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tag that can be used in a `spec` file to explicitly [disallow two conflicting packages to be installed](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-manual-dependencies.html):

> The conflicts Tag
>
> The conflicts tag is the logical complement to the requires tag. It is used to specify which packages conflict with the current package. RPM will not permit conflicting packages to be installed unless overridden with the --nodeps option.
>
> The conflicts tag has the same format as requires. It accepts a real or virtual package name and can optionally include version and release specifications or a serial number.

Comment: This answer is perfect. I did overlook that...